# Spring batch Admin : Unable to read 663 MB flat file, OutOfMemoryError

Tags: spring, tomcat7, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am using Spring Batch Admin 1.2.1 in Tomcat 7. I am trying to read 663 MB file and getting following error. I have also increased the heap size of Tomcat but of no vain. The job is pretty straight forward. It reads flat file and save it to DB with very little processing. **Please help.**

```
15:05:10,535  INFO http-apr-8181-exec-4 SimpleStepHandler:133 - Executing step: [load]
    15:05:10,981 ERROR http-apr-8181-exec-4 AbstractStep:212 - Encountered an error executing the step
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:3098)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResource(WebappClassLoader.java:1244)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResource(WebappClassLoader.java:1407)
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.exists(ClassPathResource.java:139)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy30.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:93)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor.open(ChunkMonitor.java:105)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:93)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:301)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:192)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
```

Following is my setEnv.bat file entry at TOMCAT_HOME\BIN location

```
 set JAVA_OPTS=-DENVIRONMENT=dev -Dlog4j.debug -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m  %JAVA_OPTS%
```

Below is my job configs:

```
<batch:job id="ex_Job" parent="baseJob">
    <batch:step id="load" parent="baseStep" next="Recon">
    <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="Reader" writer="Writer" processor="Processor">
                <batch:skippable-exception-classes merge="true" />
            </batch:chunk>
        <batch:listeners merge="true" />
        </batch:tasklet>
   </batch:step>    
        <batch:listeners merge="true" />
    </batch:job>
    <bean id="Reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
        <property name="skippedLinesCallback" ref="headerLineCallbackHandler" />
        <property name="resource" value="${extract.input.data.dir}/#{jobParameters['input.file']}" />
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper">
                <property name="tokenizers">
                    <map>
                        <entry key="*" value-ref="LineTokenizer" />
                        <entry key="T*" value-ref="TrailerTokenizer" />
                    </map>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMappers">
                    <map>
                        <entry key="*" value-ref="fieldSetMapper" />
                    </map>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <beans:bean id="fieldSetMapper" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughFieldSetMapper" />
    <job id="baseJob" abstract="true">
        <listeners>
            <listener ref="skipCheckingJobListener"></listener>
        </listeners>
    </job>

    <step id="baseStep" abstract="true">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk commit-interval="100" skip-limit="10000">
                <skippable-exception-classes>
                    <include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException" />
                    <include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectLineLengthException" />
                    <include class="org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException"/>
                    <include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.ConversionException"/>
                </skippable-exception-classes>
            </chunk>
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="stepExecutionListener" />
                <listener ref="genericSkipListener" />
            </listeners>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
```

Comment: looks like tomcat is trying to load the complete file by itself, can you try it without a classpath resource and a system link? by looking at the source of tomcat 6 and 7, tomcat 6 does not load the file

Comment: Is the # symbol a typo in your resource property value - should this be `${jobParameters['input.file']}`?

Comment: It might be possible that 1G is not enough to load a 663MB file into memory? What does your jvisualvm say? Did you try with a larger heap, say 2-3G?

Comment: @ChrisWhite: Using `#{}` is fine, as this expression should be interpreted by [step scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#step-scope) lazily, not by Spring when context is loaded.

Comment: I am a bit shocked: Tomcat is reading the resource in [WebappClassLoader:3098](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.26/org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader.java#3098)... Dunno.

Comment: @dma_k just curious if thats part of the spec?

Comment: @MichaelLange: I believe in certain cases this cases this behaviour is understandable (e.g. loading a `.class`), but I consider this to be a bug (fired [bug#53081](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53081)). We'll see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what's happening, but unable to verify myself.

Because your resource was injected as a ClasspathResource, the `exists` method attempts to load the entire resource in memory.  Instead, try to prepend the resource property with `file:`, so your inputReader looks like this.

```
<property name="resource" value="file:${extract.input.data.dir}/#{jobParameters['input.file']}" />
```

I've used spring batch to process multi-GB files using this approach before, with no memory issues at all.  The only time I did encounter an out-of-memory error was when the file didn't have the correct line endings, and it attempted to read the entire file for the initial line.

Good luck.